# Printing list of DictReader twice in a row produces different results

Tags: python, csv

I'm using the `csv` module to use `csv.DictReader` to read in a csv file. I am a newbie to Python and the following behavior has me stumped.

EDIT: See original question afterwards.

```
csv = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
print(list(csv)) # prints what I would expect, a sequence of OrderedDict's
print(list(csv)) # prints an empty list...
```

Is `list` somehow mutating `csv`?

*Original question:*

```
def removeFooColumn(csv):
  for row in csv:
    del csv['Foo']

csv = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
print(list(csv)) # prints what I would expect, a sequence of OrderedDict's
removeFooColum(csv)
print(list(csv)) # prints an empty list...
```

What is happening to the sequence in the `removeFooColumn` function?

Comment: What happens if you don't call `removeFooColum(csv)`?

Comment: @Heap Overflow...I think I understand now...

Comment: If i comment out the call to `removeFooColumn`, the result is the same. @Omer I have already verified that `del csv['Foo']` only deletes that one column from the dict in the iteration, and doesn't delete the whole row.

Comment: Have you ever used the pandas library? Depending on what you're doing beyond this particular operation, it might make things easier.

Comment: @LTheriault, I considered it, but seeing as I am new to Python, I wanted to understand how Python works a bit more before diving into any non-standard libraries.

Comment: @Omer, I'm so sorry... edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv.DictReader` is an <strike>generator</strike> iterator, it can only be consumed once. Here is a fix:

```
def removeFooColumn(csv):
  for row in csv:
    del row['Foo']

csv = list(csv.DictReader(csvFile))
print(csv) # prints what I would expect, a sequence of OrderedDict's
removeFooColumn(csv)
print(csv) # prints an empty list...
```

Comment: Hmmm, this works, but I don't understand *why*. Nowhere in the documentation can I find any mention that `csv.DictReader` is a "generator". How did you find that out?

Comment: I also couldn't find any mention of this in the docs. I found it out by general Python experience with generators...

Comment: Okay. Found it. It says `DictReader` "Create an object that operates like a regular `reader`". A `reader` is documented as "Return a `reader` object which will iterate over lines". An iterator is defined as follows: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator. I meant to say `csv.DictReader` is an iterator, not a generator, two different terms that I got mixed up. A generator returns a `generator iterator`.

Comment: Thanks for following up on that! Was definitely scratching my head... :)